# I need help with a word problem .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The length of a rectangle is 1 meter less than twice its width. If the area of the rectangle is 120 square meters, find the dimensions of the rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the length of the rectangle and $y$ be the width of the rectangle.

Area is given by $A=xy\implies xy=120 \tag{1}$

And according to the question, the length $x$ is $1$ less than twice the width $2y$.

$\therefore x=2y-1 \tag{2}$

Solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get $x=15$ and $y=8$.

Comment: Note that $x=-16$ and $y=-7.5$ also satisfy the equations, but can be ignored, since the dimensions must be positive...